# Hide default command line output from 'at'

Tags: command, hide, output, stdout, at-job

I was wondering how I would suppress the following output.

```
commands will be executed using /bin/ksh
job ##########.a at Mon Mar ## ##:##:## 2014
```

when using the "at - k" command. I have tried using it like

```
at -k "now + 5 hours" <<! >/dev/null
something
!
```

but I keep getting the output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` writes to stderr, not to stdout.

To redirect both, use the following:

```
at -k "now + 5 hours" <<! >/dev/null 2>&1
something
!
```

The `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect file descriptor 2 (stderr) to the same file as fd 1 (stdout).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! Doesn't seem typical for that to be considered stderr... I'm sure there's a reason though, I'm not all that interested in what it is though. Again... Thanks